# Can't bind View to ViewModel in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I am working on desktop app in WPF and I want to follow the MVVM pattern. I have my view ready and it was time to do a viewmodel. But for some reason i can't bind viewmodel to the view. 
I have tried this in XAML of the view:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="" Height="626" Width="1200" Background="#FFDEDF1A"
        DataContext="ViewModels/MainViewModel">
```

Didn't work so i tried this in the class of View:

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel(); 
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

But it doesn't work either... I tried to look it up on the internet but everyone is doing the same thing.

ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string BindingTest { get; set; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            BindingTest = "test";
          }
    }
```

And how I binded the property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= BindingTest}" Padding="10"/>
```

This is how my files look:

[image: This is how my files look]

Comment: Remove `DataContext="ViewModels/MainViewModel"` from the XAML. It's pointless and also syntactically wrong.

Comment: `InitializeComponent();` needs to be the first thing in the constructor.

Comment: try to put DataContext = new MainViewModel(); after InitializeComponent();

Comment: @BarryO'Kane That's wrong. The order does not matter at all.

Comment: @Clemens well the order *shouldn't* matter if you do it right

Comment: How does the view model look like? Does it have public properties? How do you bind to them? We can't help without these details.

Comment: @Clemens let me rephrase. In order for the code to function as expected `InitializeComponent();` needs to be the first thing in the constructor.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane No, that is not true. Try it yourself.

Comment: @JakubYaghob Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58833378/edit) your question. Do not write code in comments. Also show us how you bind to any of the view model properties.

Comment: Note that the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation in your MainViewModel is incomplete. The BindingTest property setter should call the OnPropertyChanged method. However, an initial property value should still be visible in the UI. So how do you bind?

Comment: Your code works fine, assuming you have removed the DataContext assignment from XAML. What if you assign the TextBlock's Text to a string value in XAML (instead of the Binding)? Can you see that?

Comment: @Clemens Well for some reason i does not... But i have just realized something, when i put a breakpoint in the viewmodel or in the window class it never stops there. It's like the classes don't even exist. Is there something else i can do?

Comment: You are building the Debug configuration?

Comment: @Clemens Sorry, not quite sure what do you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the DataContext in XAML, you should do something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:AssemblyName.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="" Height="626" Width="1200" Background="#FFDEDF1A">
        <Window.DataContext>
             <viewModels:MainViewModel />
        </Window.DataContext>
        <!-- Your Code Here... -->
</Window>
```

Change the **AssemblyName** to your project name.

Comment: Actually this works. Thanks to you sir and to @Clemens as well.